# Make flex-direction switch to column if there's not enough space in a row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

In the example below, what I want is to have `.inner-flexbox` have `flex-direction: row;` when its child elements can fit on a single row, but switch to `flex-direction: column;` when they cannot. I don't think media queries are what I want here because I would be basing them on whether the viewport width is greater than or less than the width of all the `<div>`s in `.inner-flexbox` in a row plus the width of the `<aside>`. Basically, I don't want the items inside `.inner-flexbox` wrapping—I want them either all in one row, or all in one column.

(distilled example): I have a flexbox that contains two items. One is a "normal" element, the other is another flexbox.

```css
.outer-wrapper
{
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: gray;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.inner-flexbox
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.inner-flexbox > div
{
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background-color: salmon;
    margin: 10px;
}

aside
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-flexbox">
    <div>Block 1</div>
    <div>Block 2</div>
    <div>Block 3</div>
  </div>
  <aside><!-- Other content here --></aside>
</div>
```

Comment: A media query would make sense here because you don't want wrapping, you want an immediate switch from horizontal to vertical.

Comment: Is there a media query that would suit these purposes? If so, I am open to the idea.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b36j7Lk1/

Comment: @Michael_B This works fine as long as you know the width of the items. That can quickly get complicated, especially if you start changing content and the items aren't the same width anymore. From my question: "I don't think media queries are what I want here because I would be basing them on whether the viewport width is greater than or less than the width of all the <div>s in .inner-flexbox in a row plus the width of the <aside>."

Comment: @Michael_B I forgot to give the <aside> a width my example until now, but as soon as I added it to your example and added flex-shrink: 0; to prevent it from being squashed, the media query fell apart. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As soon as _I don't know the size_ comes into play, script is, in 99% of all cases, necessary since CSS doesn't do overall calculations, and your is one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resorted to scripting, as @LGSon suggested. I used jQuery to compare the total width of the inner flexbox to the width of the container minus the width of the item next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: gray;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.inner-flexbox {
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.inner-flexbox>div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: salmon;
  margin: 10px;
}

aside {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-flexbox">
    <div>Block 1</div>
    <div>Block 2</div>
    <div>Block 3</div>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <!-- Other content here -->
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. I do **not** want the items in inner-flexbox to wrap. I want them either all in a single row, or all in a single column. The items inside inner-flexbox should only be in a column if there is not enough space for them to be in a row layout.